# Regex matching characters of one string in another in any order

Tags: regex, perl

Consider the following string `wizard`. I want to find if it is in another string in any order and in any case.

I tried the following

```perl
while(<>){if($_=~/(?:([wizard])(?!.*\1)){6}/i){print"0"}else{print"1"}}
```

For the inputs

```
Garry Kasparov
Bobby Fischer
Vladimir Kramnik
Wayne Drimaz
Lionel Messi
La Signora
```

It printed `111111` but it must have been `111011`.

So, I tried this instead (for the same inputs)

```
while(<>){if($_=~/(?=[wizard]{6})(?!.*(.).*\1).*/i){print"0"}else{print"1"}}
```

It again printed `111111`.
In input number 4, we can make `WaDriaz` but only one `a` is needed. Anyway, we can spell `wizard` by rearranging and in any case. Why is it not working?

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Add `use re 'debug'` and look at the output.

Comment: Perhaps `/w/ && /i/ && /z/ && /a/ && /r/ && /d/`.

Comment: Question: Do you consider the `latte` to be in `late`, or is the count important?

Comment: @ikegami Count is not important 
Please see this
> we can make `WaDriaz` but only one a is needed

Comment: Thanks a lot, @TLP That was really simple. But is there any other way to do it with a single regex? Because, if we want to do for a list of strings and each should be checked and if the string lengths are high, then it is not possible to follow this approach

Comment: @JohnBrookfields your answer is more confusing than anything else. What should be the output for "wizzard" instead of "wizard"? Same or different?

Comment: It should match that. I only want to check if we can form wizard in any way and hence count doesn't matter. That is, `wizzzzzzzzzarrrrrrrrrrrrddddddddaaaaaaaawwwwwwww` `wziadrRWzaIdD` are also applicable

Comment: @JohnBrookfields "_is there any other way to do it with a single regex_" --- well, yes, see my answer.

Comment: @JohnBrookfields Yes, there are many such answers to your question. But to demand that it is "one regex" is an unnecessary demand, your solution is not going to be better for being a single regex solution. The solutions with lookaheads `(?=.*w)` that are dynamically generated should suit your purpose well.

Comment: @JohnBrookfields Also, the `/w/ && /i/ && ..` approach is certainly doable with dynamical strings, I will add an answer to show you. But its not "single regex".

Comment: @JohnBrookfields Again, clear as mud. None of the names can be formed by reordering `wizzard`. Please just answer the question. What should be the output for "wizzard" instead of "wizard"?

Comment: Your regex checks for any character of [wizard] and checks if there at least 6, while ignoring the case of the characters, because of /i. "Wayne Drimaz" contains "WaDriaz" in this order, so it contains 7 characters of "wizard". So you get "1". Your code is correct, your assumption that it should return 0 is wrong.

Comment: Are you asking if the text contains all of the characters in "wizard" or whether the text contains a permutation of "wizard"? "Wayne Drimaz" doesn't contain a permutation of wizard.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a pure regex: do a [positive lookahead](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind) for each character

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use List::Util qw(uniq);  # before v. 1.45 in List::MoreUtils    

my $string = shift // q(wizard);

my $patt = join '', map { qq{(?=.*\Q$_\E)} } uniq split //, $string; 
# say $patt;  
#--> (?=.*w)(?=.*i)(?=.*z)(?=.*a)(?=.*r)(?=.*d)   (for wizard)

while (<DATA>) {
    say "Found '$string' in: $_" if /^$patt/is;
}

__DATA__
Garry Kasparov
Bobby Fischer
Vladimir Kramnik
Wayne Drimaz
Lionel Messi
La Signora
```

Being all in one regex, with an anchored lookahead and no overhead, this should be very fast.

The [`\Q...\E`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta) are there in case the search string contains regex-sensitive characters.

This code considers words with repeated characters (`latte`, `rare`) to "fit" a word without that (`later`).  It is clarified in comments that this is indeed the wanted behavior: repeated characters need only be found once in the target (`letter` matches `later` etc).

Answer (score 5):

The following should be quite fast (especially if you inline the subs):

```perl
use feature qw( fc say );

sub make_key {
   my %counts;
   ++$counts{$_} for split //, fc($_[0]) =~ s/\PL//rg;
   return \%counts;
}

sub search {
   my ($substr, $str) = @_;
   $str = make_key($str);
   no warnings qw( uninitialized );
   return !( grep { $str->{$_} < $substr->{$_} } keys(%$substr) );
}

my $substr = make_key("wizard");
while (<>) {
   chomp;
   say search($substr, $_) ? 0 : 1;
}
```

Unlike virtually all of the previous solutions, this one doesn't consider `latte` to be in `late`.

---

The following is a regex based solution (with some prep). This should also be quite fast (especially if you inline the subs).

```perl
use feature qw( fc say );

sub make_re {
   my $pat = join ".*?", map quotemeta, sort split //, fc($_[0]) =~ s/\PL//rg;
   return qr/$pat/s;
}

sub search {
   my ($substr, $str) = @_;
   return ( join "", sort split //, $str ) =~ $substr;
}

my $substr = make_re("wizard");   # qr/a.*?d.*?i.*?r.*?w.*?z/is
while (<>) {
   chomp;
   say search($substr, $_) ? 0 : 1;
}
```

---

Finally, a purely regexp-based solution.

```perl
use feature qw( fc say );

sub make_re {
   my %counts;
   ++$counts{$_} for split //, fc($_[0]) =~ s/\PL//rg;
   my $pat =
      join "",   
         map { "(?=".( ( ".*?" . quotemeta($_) ) x $counts{$_} ).")" }
            #sort
               keys(%counts);
   return qr/^$pat/s;
}

my $re = make_re("wizard");  # qr/^(?=.*?a)(?=.*?d)(?=.*?i)(?=.*?r)(?=.*?w)(?=.*?z)/is
while (<>) {
   say /$re/ ? 0 : 1;
}
```

---

**Unlike virtually all of the previous solutions, none of mine consider `latte` to be in `late`.**

Comment: @TLP Re `<=`, No. We're doing `!any { not_found() }`

Comment: @TLP I'll add the `use feature` when at computer later

Answer (score 4):

It's just a simple matter of using a positive lookahead for every character.

```perl
my @stars = (
  'Garry Kasparov',
  'Bobby Fischer',
  'Vladimir Kramnik',
  'Wayne Drimaz',
  'Lionel Messi',
  'La Signora'
);

say /^(?=.*w)(?=.*i)(?=.*z)(?=.*a)(?=.*r)(?=.*d)/i ? 0 : 1 for @stars;
```

This outputs `111011`.

Comment: To prevent `latte` from being found in `late`, use `/^(?=.*a)(?=.*e)(?=.*l)(?=.*t.*t)/is`

Answer (score 4):

I find canonicalization of the inputs and the pattern to be a more generalizable and understandable approach:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub canonchars {
    my %c;
    $c{$_} = undef for map lc, grep /\S/, split //, $_[0];
    sort keys %c;
}

sub pattern {
    map "$_.*", canonchars($_[0]);
}

my %canonical;

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    last unless $line =~ /\S/;
    push $canonical{join '', canonchars($line)}->@*, $line;
}

my $pat = qr/@{[join '', pattern('wizard')]}/;

for my $k (keys %canonical) {
    if ($k =~ $pat) {
        print for $canonical{$k}->@*;
    }
}

__DATA__
Garry Kasparov
Bobby Fischer
Vladimir Kramnik
Wayne Drimaz
Lionel Messi
La Signora
```

Output:

```
C:\Temp> perl t.pl
Wayne Drimaz
```

There is a lot of logic you are trying to fit into a regular expression pattern, and every edge case you find and fix will make it more complicated and more fragile.

Comment: Speaking of edge cases, what if they want to look for the characters `"wizard+"` or something else that's special in a RE? (Easy fix if you want to make it robust enough to handle things like that, at least, thanks to `\Q...\E`).

Comment: @Shawn That's why canonicalization and pattern generation go into their own individually documentable methods. Then, it is easier to keep track of individual changes/enhancements. This is just an illustration.

Comment: If I read this correctly, this considers `latte` to be found in `late`. Not sure if that's ok.

Answer (score 4):

No need for regular expressions... they just complicate things, especially if you're not looking for a string you know ahead of time. Just look for each character in turn after normalizing their cases.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

sub contains_chars {
    my ($needle, $haystack) = @_;
    $haystack = lc $haystack;
    my %positions;
    for my $char (split //, lc $needle) {
        my $p = index $haystack, $char, $positions{$char}//0;
        return 1 if $p < 0;
        $positions{$char} = $p + 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

while (<DATA>) {
    print contains_chars("wIzArD", $_);
}
print "\n";

__DATA__
Garry Kasparov
Bobby Fischer
Vladimir Kramnik
Wayne Drimaz
Lionel Messi
La Signora
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Shawn But I already have a solution without regex. But I want to do it with regex. That's why I added a tag regex.

Answer (score 4):

This a black art way that out of order matching can occur.
Each character in the source string is visited only once.
No need to recurse the string from the beginning for each letter.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
   if ( $line =~ /
     (?:
       .*?
       (?:
           (?(1)(?!))(w)
         | (?(2)(?!))(i)
         | (?(3)(?!))(z)
         | (?(4)(?!))(a)
         | (?(5)(?!))(r)
         | (?(6)(?!))(d)
       )
     ){6}/ix ) { print $line, "\n" }
}

__DATA__
Garry Kasparov
Bobby Fischer
Vladimir Kramnik
Wayne Drimaz
Lionel Messi
La Signora
```

> Wayne Drimaz

Captures can exist in two states, defined or undefined.
The essence of this black art is to use the state of captures as flags
to insure all the items are matched in the out-of-order state.

The above can also be written this way with the same result.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
   if ( $line =~ /
     (?im)
     ^ 
     (?>
        .*? 
        (?:
           w ( )       # (1)
         | i ( )       # (2)
         | z ( )       # (3)
         | a ( )       # (4)
         | r ( )       # (5)
         | d ( )       # (6)
        )
     )+
     (?= \1 \2 \3 \4 \5 \6 )
   /x ) { print $line, "\n" }
}

__DATA__
Garry Kasparov
Bobby Fischer
Vladimir Kramnik
Wayne Drimaz
Lionel Messi
La Signora
```

Comment: If I read this correctly, this considers `latte` to be found in `late`. Not sure if that's ok.

Comment: @ikegami - The slowest this is going to get is 1/3 rd the speed of the pure lookaheads. The fastest is many times more. The pure lookahead will fail faster. If the pure lookahead actually consumes the line, its speed will match the flag version. The two extreme conditions are: 1. Equal required chars at the end, one match then at the beginning the next match. 2.  No match at all. It would take some serious engine knowledge to know why these things are true.

Comment: Add an anchor and /s to the first

Comment: As for speed, only benchmarks will tell. Lookahead could easily be faster if it was case-sensitive and ASCII-only. But with the scenario at hand and the tweaks I mentioned above, your probably right.

Answer (score 2):

Just adding a simple variant of `/w/ && /i/ && /z/ ...` solution I mentioned in comments. If you want this solution to match a lot of different strings, instead of lining the regexes together with `&&`, you can simply loop over the characters. A useful tool is to use the `&&=` operator to mimic the behaviour of a long string of conditions. This will also allow us to short-circuit the matching if we find a mismatch, giving us a speed benefit.

For example:

```
/a/ && /b/ && /c/
```

Equivalent to

```
my $match = 1;
for my $w (qw(a b c)) {
    $match &&= (/$w/);    # $match = ($match && /$w/)
}
```

To remember the count of letters, i.e. whether `latte` should be considered to be a substring of `late`, you can simply use the substitution operator `s///` instead of match operator `m//`. I added the multi-letter criteria, and added two test cases to demonstrate.

I like this solution because of the simplicity, but thereby not said it is the best one.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $word = "wizzard";

while (<DATA>) {
    print search($_, $word), " $_";
}

sub search {
    my ($str, $substr) = @_;
    my $match = 1;                        # assume true
    for my $w (split //, $substr) {       # for each char in substr...
        $match &&= ($str =~ s/\Q$w//i);   # ...remove character
        return 0 if not $match;           # ...return false if no match found
    }
    return 1 if $match;
}

__DATA__
wizard
wizzard
Garry Kasparov
Bobby Fischer
Vladimir Kramnik
Wayne Drimaz
Wayne Drimazz
Lionel Messi
La Signora
```

Output:

```
0 wizard
1 wizzard
0 Garry Kasparov
0 Bobby Fischer
0 Vladimir Kramnik
0 Wayne Drimaz
1 Wayne Drimazz
0 Lionel Messi
0 La Signora
```

If you do not care about multi-letter matching, just replace `s///` with `m//`.